# Tshark - Export packet info from pcap to cvs

Tags: csv, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I am trying to programmatically capture a stream of packets by using `Tshark`. The simplified terminal command I am using is:

```
tshark -i 2 -w output.pcap
```

This is pretty straightforward, but I then need to get a `.csv` file in order to easily analyze the information captured.
By opening the `.pcap` file in Wireshark and exporting it in .csv what I get is a file structured as follows:

```
"No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Length","Info"
```

but,again, I need to do this in an automatic way. So I tried using the command:

```
tshark -r output.pcap -T fields -e frame.number -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e frame.len -e frame.time -e frame.time_relative -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv
```

but I can not find anywhere the name of the `"Info"` field I get when manually exporting the .csv.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is no name for the Info field, because is not a filterable field like ip.src, frame.time etc..
You can find an overview of all the display filters in the [Display Filter Reference](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/).

Comment: I went through the whole list yesterday and I was afraid I would not have find it as the Info field is not a filterable entity. But when I manually export the .pcap to .csv the Info entry is there, so there must be a way I can use in order to select it with the terminal command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can if you use the latest Development Release.
See [Wireshark Bug 2892](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2892).
Download the [Development Release Version 1.9.0](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).
Use the following command:
$ tshark -i 2 -T fields -e frame.time -e col.Info
Output
Feb 28, 2013 20:58:24.604635000 Who has 10.10.128.203?  Tell 10.10.128.1
Feb 28, 2013 20:58:24.678963000 Who has 10.10.128.163?  Tell 10.10.128.1

Note
-e col.Info,
Use capital I

Answer (score 0):

How about directly exporting the packets to a csv file.

> `sudo tshark > fileName.csv`