# convert pcap files with all the fields to csv

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, tshark

Already seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092380/export-pcap-data-to-csv-timestamp-bytes-uplink-downlink-extra-info), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112389/tshark-export-packet-info-from-pcap-to-cvs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326230/how-can-i-convert-a-pcap-into-csv-using-python) but I want to convert the whole pcap files with `ALL` the fields using `tshark`.
I have quite a few `pcap` files that need conversion. I don't mind using python or `tshark`

The question is if its possible to convert `without` manually entering the required field names (I want all the field names by default)?

tvm

Comment: It's unclear what this csv will look like (you should provide example text). While you're at it, please make sure the question follows this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: csv will hold all the cols with its values? for example if the pcap has 10 cols with 10 values then they are just comma separated which could be uploaded to a database. are you asking from a python perspective or is there something else i am just missing?

Comment: Related: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question to conform to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python and tshark to automate this:

```
import os

for file in os.listdir('your/path-to-pcap/'):
  output_csv = file + '.csv'
  os.system(f"tshark -N n -r ./test/{file} -T fields -e frame.number -e _ws.col.Time -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Length -e _ws.col.Info -E header=y -E separator=, > {output_csv}")
```